# Is the conjectured noncommutative heavy scalar "brother" of the already detected Higgs boson is a pseudo scalar?

Tags: grand-unification, majorana-fermions, non-commutative-geometry

This is a technical (may be trivial?) question about this [sigma scalar field advertised by Chamseddine and Connes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1030) to improve the electroweak vacuum stability involved by the weak mass of the already found Higgs-like particle.

**Is it a scalar or a pseudo scalar field?**

(motivation: I was looking for a possible connection with Majoron models)

Comment: The undiscovered scalar field is supposed to mix with the Higgs field. Can a scalar field mix with a pseudoscalar field?

Comment: You have a habit of asking rambling 'philosophical' questions and then peppering them with weakly related technical questions.  This is very bad form, since the whole point of StackExchange is to figure out the best answer to a _single answerable question_.  I am voting to put this question on hold until you decide which of your two questions is the question you want answered.

Comment: Dear @user1504 I wish my last edit complies better with the StackExchange philosophy now ;-)

Comment: Yes, much better.  I don't think I can remove my close vote but I think the question is fine now.

Comment: It's my pleasure to learn through Physics StackExchange users!

Comment: @user1504 I have said leave open, and maybe others will do this too as the question is fine now :-). I always think the mixing philosophical issues into technical questions is a bit confusing, at least for me ...